# Scrapy XML Document

Tags: python, scrapy

I am just new to Python and `scrapy`. I am trying to extract the data from multiple XML documents. I have found the XML here they range from `<strong>CourseId=1</strong>` all the way up to `<strong>CourseID=4500</strong>`:

Example 1:
    http://www.myskills.gov.au/DesktopModules/Services/api/RegisteredTrainers/GetOfferedTrainers?LocationID=0&Distance=25&IsExplicit=false&CourseId=1

Example 1:

http://www.myskills.gov.au/DesktopModules/Services/api/RegisteredTrainers/GetOfferedTrainers?LocationID=0&Distance=25&IsExplicit=false&CourseId=2

My scrapy code is below. When I run it, I get a `TypeError: unbound method body_as_unicode() must be called with the XMLResonse instance as first argument`.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import XmlXPathSelector
from myProject.items import RTOData
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.http import XmlResponse


class myProjectSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myProject'
    allowed_domains = ['myskills.gov.au']
    start_urls =     ['http://www.myskills.gov.au/DesktopModules/Services/api/RegisteredTrainers/GetOfferedTrainers?LocationID=0&Distance=25&IsExplicit=false&CourseId=1']

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
     x = XmlXPathSelector(XmlResponse)
     Latitude = x.select('//ArrayOfRegisteredTrainerLocationOfferedItem/RegisteredTrainerLocationOfferedItem/Latitude').extract()
     Longitude = x.select('//ArrayOfRegisteredTrainerLocationOfferedItem/RegisteredTrainerLocationOfferedItem/Longitude').extract()
     RTOCode = x.select('//ArrayOfRegisteredTrainerLocationOfferedItem/RegisteredTrainerLocationOfferedItem/RTOCode').extract()
     SiteName = x.select('//ArrayOfRegisteredTrainerLocationOfferedItem/RegisteredTrainerLocationOfferedItem/SiteName').extract()
```

Can someone tell me if I'm on the right path please?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Where is `body_as_unicode` part?

Comment: Full Traceback below: